# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

can someone help me to understand want seam to  be the problem I Create a model in a e-comers website.

models:

```
    class Customer (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

then in views i add it to the cart:

```
def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []

    context = {'items': items}
    return render(request, 'ecomeres/cart.html', context)
```

Comment: You have shown your code but you did not describe your problem. What is it that is not working for you. What did you try. We need more details if we are to help you.

Answer (score 3):

A `OneToOneField` actually is a `ForeignKey` field with a `unique=True` constraint
and a `OneToOneField` field does not mean that the referenced model always has `customer` object(in your case). This is why in some case if `user.customer` for some user not exists then it raises an `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`.

So you have to either use `try-except` and raise `exception` if object does not exists.

In views.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def cart(request):
    try:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            customer = request.user.customer
            order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, complete=False)
            items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        else:
            items = []

        context = {'items': items}
        return render(request, 'ecomeres/cart.html', context)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        # hanlde your case when model object does not exist.
    else:
        # this block is excuted only if try except don't raise exception
```

Or you can also user Python's `hasattr()` method.

```
def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if hasattr(request.user, 'customer')
            customer = request.user.customer
            order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, complete=False)
            items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        else:
            # handle if request.user has no customer
    else:
        items = []

    context = {'items': items}
    return render(request, 'ecomeres/cart.html', context)
```

You can see more details about `OneToOneField` in official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) where you will get to know about both `ObjectDoesNotExist` and `hasattr`